# Order a django queryset by ManyToManyField = Value

Tags: python, django, django-models

If have some models like:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Thing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I can do a filter:

```
Thing.objects.filter(tags__name='foo')
Thing.objects.filter(tags__name__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```

But is it possible to order a queryset on the tags value?

```
Thing.objects.order_by(tags__name='foo')
Thing.objects.order_by(tags__name__in=['foo','bar'])
```

What I would expect (or like) back in this example, would be ALL Thing models, but ordered where they have a Tag/Tags that I know.  I don't want to filter them out, but bring them to the top.

I gather this is possible using the FIELD operator, but seemingly I can only make it work on columns in that models table, e.g. title, but not on linked tables.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** After having accepted the below solution, I realised a bug/limitation with it.

If a particular Thing has multiple Tags, then (due to the left join done behind the scenes in the SQL) it will produce one entry for that Thing, for *each* Tag that it has.  With a True or False for each Tag that matches or not.

Adding .distinct() to the queryset helps only slightly, limiting to a max of 2 rows per Thing (i.e. one tagged=True, and one tagged=False).

I know what I need to do in the SQL, which is to MAX() the CASE(), and then GROUP BY Thing's primary key, which means I will get one row per Thing, and if there has been any tag matches, tagged will be True (and False otherwise).

I see the way that people typically achieve this *kind* of thing is to use .values() like this:

```
Thing.objects.values('pk').annotate(tagged=Max(Case(...)))
```

But the result is only pk and tagged, I need the whole Thing model as the result.  So I've managed to achieve what I want, thusly:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Max, BooleanField

tags = ['music'] # for example

queryset = Thing.objects.all().annotate(tagged=Max(Case(
    When(tags__name__in=tags, then=True),
    default=False,
    output_field=BooleanField()
)))
queryset.query.group_by = ['pk']
queryset.order_by('-tagged')
```

This seems to work, but the group by mechanism feels weird/hacky. Is it acceptable/reliable to group in this way?

Sorry for the epic updated :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try annotate the query with the [conditional](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) value that turns true when the tag is in the list you provide

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

Thing.objects.annotate(tag_is_known=Case(
    When(tags__name__in=['foo', 'bar'], then=1),
    default=0,
    output_field=IntegerField()
))
```

Next we use that annotation we called `tag_is_known` to sort with `order_by()`:

```
Thing.objects.annotate(tag_is_known=...).order_by('tag_is_known')
```

**Boolean version**

```
Thing.objects.annotate(tag_is_known=Case(
    When(tags__name__in=['foo', 'bar'], then=True),
    default=False,
    output_field=BooleanField()
))
```

Comment: Did it work for you ? because I didn't check the syntax and I was about to suggest using `BooleanField` instead of `IntegerField`

Comment: P.S. if the syntax is incorrect, please feel free to edit the code snippet in the answer (I'm unable to check it at the moment)

Comment: Yes, it worked great thanks.  Except for my usual mistake of not inverting the sort :) I also just changed the annotation name to just 'tagged', but thanks a lot!